# How to use Regex Expression in Async Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following code and it produces an error that regular expression isn't supported by it. I believe `Async` is converting it to an `SQL` statement and that is making it fail?

```
Regex emailRegEx = new Regex(@"^.*" + emailDomain + "$");

var peoplesWithEmail = await personService.Query().Where(p => p.Emails.Any(e => emailRegEx.Match(e.EmailAddress).Success == true)).ToListAsync();
```

the error message

> "ExceptionMessage": "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match Match(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

So what is the work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes because Entity Framework is translating LINQ to SQL, it is failing.

Regex isn't supported by LINQ to SQL, however, you can use `String.StartsWith`, `String.EndsWith` and `String.Contains`

```
var peoplesWithEmail = await personService.Query()
       .Where(p => p.Emails.Any(e => e.EndsWith(emailDomain)).ToListAsync();
```